# I have a gift badge. It won't let me gift

Tags: marvel-contest-champions

I click on send a gift, And it shows no items. I can't buy any or send any gifts. It brings up the blank screen and shows no items to buy or otherwise. Don't know what to do. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Gifting badge is a badge which allows a user to send gifts to friends and other users. This doesn’t mean that you could send gifts from your own inventory in fact you have to pay real money to be able to send gifts.